# O que significa quando o console retorna a própria função?

Tags: javascript, funções

Editado. O console está retornando a própria função como resposta, não o resultado da função.

O objetivo é que a função diga se um valor é ou não maior que o outro.

```
let primeiraVariavel = 34;
let segundaVariavel = 10;

function resultado() {
 return primeiraVariavel > segundaVariavel ? "verdadeiro" : "falso";
}
console.log(resultado);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Porque você explicitamente está mandando exibir a função:

```
console.log(resultado);
```

E não o retorno dela. Para exibir o retorno você precisa efetuar a chamada da função:

```
console.log(resultado());
// ------------------^^
```

Assim será exibido `verdadeiro`.

```js
let primeiraVariavel = 34;
let segundaVariavel = 10;

function resultado() {
 return primeiraVariavel > segundaVariavel ? "verdadeiro" : "falso";
}

console.log(resultado());
```

Answer (score 2):

> console.log(resultado); substitua por console.log(resultado());

Quando você não coloca o "()", você faz apenas referência e não chama a função.